# How do I get "--base-href" to not expand to an absolute path when building using npm?

Tags: angular, npm, href, radix, npm-build

I'm using Angular 14 and NPM 8.  I have this command for building my artifact ...

```
npm run build -- --source-map --base-href=/my-app/ --output-path=dist/my-app/
```

The problem is, when my dist/my-app/index.html file is generated it contains the full path to my local machine

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="C:/Program Files/Git/my-app/">
```

How do I run my build command such that my base href is only what is included after my "base-href" flag?

Comment: I just tested in my end and your command generated the expected output (I removed the extra `--`  which is probably a typo).  Can you also add your `tsconfig.json` file to the question? Is `baseUrl` value `"./"` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `baseUrl` property in your `tsconfig.json` file like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  },
}
```

> `baseUrl` lets you set a base directory to resolve non-absolute module names.
>
> You can define a root folder where you can do absolute file
> resolution.
>
> With `"baseUrl": "./"` inside the project TypeScript will look for files starting at the same folder as the `tsconfig.json`.